# How to calculate the 'Coefficient of determination' for a linear model in R?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, linear-regression

I have the following set of `x` and `y` values:

```
x = c(1:150)
y = x^-.5 * 155 + (runif(length(x), min=-3, max=3))
```

And run a linear regression on the data:

```
plot(x, y, log="xy", cex=.5)

model = lm(log(y) ~ log(x))
model
```

Now I'd like to have a measure for the quality of the regression and was told that people usually use R^2 ('Coefficient of determination'), which should be close to one.

How can I easily calculate the value in R? I've seen that residuals etc. are already calculated.

Comment: Try `summary(model)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  `summary(model)` to print a detailed output into de console. You can also use `str` to explore the extructure of an object, for example `str(summary(model))` this is useful when you can to extract part of that output using `$`.

```
result <- summary(model)   # summary of the model
str(result)                # see structure of the summary
result$r.squared           # extract R squared (coefficient of determination)
```

`result` contains both, R.squared and Adjusted R squared, see for example the following output

```
Residual standard error: 0.09178 on 148 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9643,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.964 
F-statistic:  3992 on 1 and 148 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

that output is just the last part of  `summary(model)` printed in the console